# Unix checking if two paths are the same

Tags: unix, symlink

I have a path A which is a symlink to path B. Path C is some different.

How can i check, if the destination is identical?

I want to get true in case:

```
A = B
A = A
B = B
C = C
```

I want to get false in case:

```
A = C
B = C
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use readlink to get symlink destination.

Comment: Use `ls -Li` to get the inode numbers - where they are the same, the names refer to the same file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the inode numbers.

```
touch m n    # Create m and n
ln -s m o    # Symlink o to m

ls -lLi m n o    # Look at inodes of all files, see o and m are the same.
13132212 -rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  0 10 Dec 15:18 m
13132213 -rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  0 10 Dec 15:18 n
13132212 -rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  0 10 Dec 15:18 o
```

So, if you want to get the inode numbers in a script, you could do this:

```
minode=$(ls -Li m | awk '{print $1}')
echo $minode
13132212

oinode=$(ls -Li o | awk '{print $1}')
echo $oinode
13132212
```

and test like this:

```
[ $minode -eq $oinode ] && echo equal
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea with inodes. I will use stat -Lc %i a